# How do I turn this responsive Navigation into a mobile Menu?

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

I have a 100% width x 75px height navy navigation bar. I have a logo in the center of the navigation (a retro badge) that ideally is positioned extending this bar upward (think of a belt buckle).

However, I want this menu to disappear and turn into one of those square icon mobile menus when it gets smaller (and have the 'logo; move just below the menu). I've looked at about 4 tutorials now and none of them have worked for me.

I am using the 'Responsive Grid System' to build my website.

Design Reference: [CLICK ME (:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Noz7M.jpg)

```
<div id="navigation">
    <nav id="primary_nav">
        <ul>  
              <li><a href="">home</a></li>                  
              <li><a href="">about</a></li>                             
              <li><a href="">services</a></li>          
              <li><a id="logo" href="/"><img src="images/CarpetRepair_Logo.png" alt="Logo"></a></li>
              <li><a href="">photos</a></li>        
              <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
              <li><a id="FB" href="/"><img src="images/FB_Logo.jpg" alt="Facebook"></a></li>            
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div> <!-- navigation end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to simply contain your navigation links within a select tag. Which are rendered differently across mobile devices.

```
<select>
<option data-link="url-of-lin">Link 1</option>
... repeat ...
</select>
```

You can then use javascript/jquery to navigate to the location stored in the data- attribute.

Then you simply hide your desktop/full navigation, and style the mobile one to have a nice icon.

Here is a demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ldxpo - It gives a very basic design. I have made the select menu semi-transparent so you can see what is going on. You can style/update this as needed, but should be a basic starting point.

Hope this helps.